# How to increment variable by 1 to limit, then rewind and repeat increment - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable holding a number, say 1. I want it to increment to 10. After reaching 10, it should then decrement to 1. Then again it should increment. I made a solution like;

```
var a = 1;
var i;
for(i=0;i<20;i++){
  //do something with var
  a++;
  if(a == 10){
    a = 1;
  }
}
```

Is there any simpler or better method for the same?

Comment: That would create an infinite loop... Are you animating something?

Comment: This code is invalid. `var` is a reserved word and cannot be used as an identifier. Please make sure to post *valid* code - and hopefully code that shows the explained behavior.

Comment: Sorry.. Corrected the code

Comment: When you "corrected" the first `var`, making it `i` it confuses what you're asking. You still have `var` in there but you have `i++` twice now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(i=0,a=1;i<20;i++,a++){
  //do something with var
  if(a==10){
    a = 1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Using the modulo operator (`%`) is quite useful in these cases.

```
var x = 1;

//loop

//process

//increment
x = (x % 10) + 1; //1
```

Comment: @user2864740 Yeah, I am so used having 0 based index that I haven't thought about it. Fixed the example.

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to wrap back to 1 instead of 0, use the mod operator before the increment.

```
var a = 1;
for (i = 0; i < 20; ++i) 
{ 
  console.log(a); 
  a = (a % 10) + 1; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=0,a=1; i<20; i++,a++){
  //do something with var
  a==10 ? a=1 : null ;
}
```